# MPMoviePlayerController does not change Orientation in full-Screen mode in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app i support only portrait mode and use `UINavigationController` as `RootViewController`. But when i am playing movie using `MPMoviePlayerController` and Player is Fullscreen than i want it to support both `landscape` mode Also.

Does this using this great code by @ChrisBallinger [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580753/mpmovieplayercontroller-rotating-in-full-screen-while-the-parent-view-controller/13580987#comment27440451_13580987https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580753/mpmovieplayercontroller-rotating-in-full-screen-while-the-parent-view-controller/13580987#comment27440451_13580987) in iOS6 but its not working in `iOS5` After long search on google i am not able to find the solution so posted here. Please help with this problem.

I have also tried to subclassing the `navigationcontroller` and set the Rotate code it [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631997/mpmovieplayercontroller-full-screen-orientation-issue) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sandbox app:
https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

The solution is easy:

in interface (h file) :

```
    BOOL rotated;
```

in implementation (m file):
1. rewrite

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return rotated;
    }
```

2 call [self setup]

```
    -(void) setup { 
    rotated = YES; 
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft]; 
    rotated = NO; 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

what you will have to do is...

first implement notification in viewdidload method like below...

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(rotate:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Now implement that rotate method like below..

```
 #pragma mark - Rotate Screen Method
- (void)rotate:(NSNotification *)n {
//    if (!isFullScreen)
//        return;
switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);//playerview is view in which  you have added MPMoviePlayerViewController object
        playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
        playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,768, 1024);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: No its just changing My playerView Size. But i don't Wanna do that i want only change orientation when player is full screen. Code from ChrisBallinger doing that in iOS6 so i think it can be possible in iOS5.